# Validation Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have html auth form and validation for it. So, how can I customize a script on that when checking email and the password it checked also symbols (something like `preg_match`)?

Here is code of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Validation
        $("#sky-form").validate({                   
            // Rules for form validation
            rules:
                {
                    email:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 20
                    }
                },

            // Messages for form validation
            messages:
                {
                    email:
                    {
                        required: 'Please enter your email address',
                        email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: 'Please enter your password'
                    }
                },                  

            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {
                 error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
    });         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom validation function like below

```
$.validator.addMethod('methodName', function (value, element, param) {
    // Validation Here

    return isValid; // return true/false
}, 'Error Message');

$('#sky-form').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            methodName: true
        }
    }
});
```

For example purpose suppose you have confirm password field in your form(i.e. text box with id = confirmPswd )

Now for checking both password same or not you have a custom validation meyhod like below

```
$.validator.addMethod('validatePassword', function (value, element, param) {
    return value==$("#confirmPswd").val(); 
}, 'Password and Confirm Password should be same');

$('#sky-form').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            validatePassword: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry,i'm not powerfull in Jquery))Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Added an Password validation method. You can have a look.

Comment: Has jquery any functions like preg_match?

Comment: Not sure on that. I suggest to check out "http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/" site for detail understanding on validation plugin